# Netsuite get SalesOrder transactions from an array of internal IDs

Tags: php, netsuite

I am looking to get an array of SalesOrders based on Netsuite Internal IDs.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
<?php

// Collect record references to sales orders by internal ID.
$salesOrderIds = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
$salesOrders = [];

foreach ($salesOrderIds as $id) {
    $ref = new RecordRef();
    $ref->internalId = $id;
    $ref->type = RecordType::salesOrder;
    $salesOrders[] = $ref;
}

// Prepare Sales Orders as field for basic search.
$field = new SearchMultiSelectField();
$field->operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator::anyOf;
$field->searchValue = $salesOrders; // I have also tried a RecordRefList here as well with no luck.

// Declare search to search sales order transactions with the internal id multiselect field above.
$basic = new TransactionSearchBasic();
$basic->type = RecordType::salesOrder;
$basic->internalId = $field; // Expected type is correct: SearchMultiSelectField

// Set the search record within the search request.
$search = new SearchRequest();
$search->searchRecord = $basic;

// This is based on application code and is working as expected. 
// As far as i'm concerned, this is out of scope of the question (to my knowledge).
$response = $this->basicSearch->queryNetsuite($search, RecordType::salesOrder);
```

The response I get with `string` or `integer` values for `$ref->internalId` is:

```
class NetSuite\Classes\Status#480 (2) {
    public $statusDetail =>
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      class NetSuite\Classes\StatusDetail#557 (4) {
        public $code =>
        string(20) "INVALID_SEARCH_VALUE"
        public $message =>
        string(35) "You need to provide a search value."
        public $afterSubmitFailed =>
        NULL
        public $type =>
        string(5) "ERROR"
      }
    }
    public $isSuccess =>
    bool(false)
  }
```

And when I look at the `SearchMultiSelectField` class to see what the `searchValue` is, it is exactly what I'm providing; `RecordRef[]`

```
class SearchMultiSelectField {
    public $searchValue;
    public $operator;
    static $paramtypesmap = array(
        "searchValue" => "RecordRef[]",
        "operator" => "SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator",
    );
}
```

---

#### How can I get a list or Sales Orders via Netsuites PHP toolkit when passing an array of internal ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution, I found a reference deep in another part of the application. Truthfully, I'm not sure what the difference is. I've gone through this 2-3x and while i'm sure I'm missing something obvious, I *think* i'm linking up the same variables in the same spots, even though in this situation I'm linking up values in place rather than in the original question I was building each piece individually and then linking them together in the end. Conceptually they seem to be the same thing. Either way, hope this helps someone in the future.

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$tranSearchBasic = new TransactionSearchBasic();
$tranSearchBasic->internalId = new SearchMultiSelectField();
$tranSearchBasic->internalId->operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator::anyOf;

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $internalIdField = new RecordRef();
    $internalIdField->internalId = $id;
    $internalIdField->type = RecordType::salesOrder;

    $tranSearchBasic->internalId->searchValue[] = $internalIdField;
}

$searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
$searchRequest->searchRecord = $tranSearchBasic;

// Same out of scope application code.
$response = $this->basicSearch->queryNetsuite($searchRequest, RecordType::salesOrder);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while since I've worked with PHP, but aren't you missing the array index here?

```
foreach ($salesOrderIds as $id) {
    $ref = new RecordRef();
    $ref->internalId = $id;
    $ref->type = RecordType::salesOrder;
    $salesOrders[MISSING INDEX] = $ref;
}
```

Comment: That answer is not helpful. `$array[] = $x;` appends a value to the end of an array. You do not need to use an index to [push into an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).